# Filling a string buffer when using Ocilib

Tags: c++, c, oracle-call-interface

I'm using [Ocilib](http://orclib.sourceforge.net/) to perform a bulk insert on a Oracle database but I'm having some trouble while filling a string buffer.

The documentation says:

> For string/RAW arrays, the input array
> MUST BE a contiguous block of data and
> not an array of pointers. So to bind
> an array of 10 elements for a
> varchar2(30) column, binded variable
> must be a like array[10][31]

And a sample proceeds to fill a buffer like this:

```
...
char tab_str[1000][21];
...
OCI_BindArrayOfStrings(st, ":s", (char*) tab_str, 20, 0);
...

for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
    sprintf(tab_str[i],"Name %d",i+1);
}
...
```

I'm trying to fill the string buffer while looping through a std::vector of MyClass. MyClass has a std::string member.

I'm trying to use the std::string::copy method to copy over the string contents to the buffer. But I don't know exactly how to index the buffer to do it.

```
...
OCI_BindArrayOfStrings(st, ":f2", NULL, VCHAR_SIZE, 0);
char** vc_buffer = (char**)OCI_BindGetData(OCI_GetBind(st, 2));
...
int i = 0;
for(vector<MyClass>::const_iterator it = myVec.begin(); it != myVec.end(); ++it)
{
    /* 1st try */ it->m_string.copy((vc_buffer + (i * VCHAR_SIZE)), VCHAR_SIZE);
    /* 2nd try */ it->m_string.copy(vc_buffer[i], VCHAR_SIZE);
    ++i;
    ...
}
...
```

The first way gives me buggy data in the database. The second makes me hit a null pointer.

What I'm doing wrong?

**PS**:

The second approach, along the approach proposed by Alessandro Vergani below, results in null strings inserted. The first approach gives this (somewhat bizarre) result:

[image: database contents]

The gvim window shows what it's supposed to look like, the apex screen shows what ends up in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Try:

```
std::vector<char> tab_str(myVec.size() * (VCHAR_SIZE + 1));
...
OCI_BindArrayOfStrings(st, ":s", &tab_str[0], VCHAR_SIZE, 0);
...
int offset = 0;
for(vector<MyClass>::const_iterator it = myVec.begin(); it != myVec.end(); ++it, offset += VCHAR_SIZE)
{
    it->m_string.copy(&tab_str[offset], VCHAR_SIZE);
    ...        
}
...
```

I'm not sure you need to add the null terminator: if not, remove the `-1` from the copy and remove the second line.

Comment: Vergani The buffer is zero-filled, therefore there's no need for a null terminator. I can't see how this is different than the first way I posted - can you explain? The results are the same.

Comment: The difference is mainly on how the buffer is allocated (by your code instead of the library). BTW: does the first example you posted work?

Comment: I made a fix (changed the size of buffer to include the null terminator, according to OCILIB documentation). Try it

Comment: Oops, edited the question while you changed your answer. I'll try it again and update the question again.

Comment: Vergani I'm really thankful! Taking into account the size plus one, due to the null terminator, fixed it all! I never saw that in the docs. Thank you!