# C Program: setting up array of strings when length is not known at compile time

Tags: c

I'm trying adapt the example code shown in the "Array Interface Example" section here,

[http://orclib.sourceforge.net/doc/html/group_*g*_bind.html](http://orclib.sourceforge.net/doc/html/group__g__bind.html)

where they place an array of strings, `tab_str`, into `OCI_BindArrayOfStrings` using:

```
char tab_str[1000][21];
...
OCI_BindArrayOfStrings(st, ":s", (char*) tab_str, 20, 0);
```

The problem is, the above example knows the array length at compile time, whereas I have to download this length from a database when the program is run. So I'd like to create an array of strings, called `my_tab_str` and place it in the following line of code:

```
OCI_BindArrayOfStrings(st, ":s", (char*) my_tab_str, 20, 0);
```

My question is how to set up `my_tab_str`? Here's my code (compiled using `gcc -std=C89`):

```
int i, arraysize;
char person_name[20] = "";
char * my_tab_str;
...
strncpy(person_name, "John Smith", 19);
arraysize = <this value is downloaded from database>;
...
my_tab_str = malloc( arraysize * sizeof(char) * (strlen(person_name)+1) );
for(i=0;i<arraysize;i++) {
    strncpy( my_tab_str[i], person_name, strlen(person_name) );
}
```

The goal is to place "John Smith" (e.g 10 bytes) plus a null termination character (which I think is automatically added by the compiler) into each element of the array of strings `my_tab_str`.

I'm getting the compile warning: `warning: passing argument 1 of 'strncpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast
/usr/include/string.h:131: note: expected 'char * __restrict__' but argument is of type 'char'`

Note that the function `OCI_BindArrayOfStrings` is described here:

[http://orclib.sourceforge.net/doc/html/group_*g*_bind.html#ga502cd4785691b17955f5d99276e48884](http://orclib.sourceforge.net/doc/html/group__g__bind.html#ga502cd4785691b17955f5d99276e48884)

and expects an array of string as an argument. See the example code at the first link above for an example implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>It's not entirely clear from your post what that function expects as an argument.  I'm going to assume it's a `char **`.</s>

In that case, you need to do something like this:

```
// Allocate an array of pointers
char **my_tab_str = calloc(arraysize, sizeof(*my_tab_str));

// Allocate room for each string in turn
for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++) {
    // person_name comes from somewhere
    const int len = strlen(person_name);
    my_tab_str[i] = calloc(len+1, sizeof(*my_tab_str[i]));
    strncpy(my_tab_str[i], person_name, len);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, so it looks like that function takes a `char *` which points to a contiguous 1D array of all the strings concatenated, along with the number of strings, and the length of each string.  In which case, you'll need to do something like this:

```
const int len = strlen(person_name);

// Big 1D array
char *my_tab_str = calloc(arraysize*(len+1), sizeof(*my_tab_str));

// Put each string into the 1D array, at regular intervals
for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++) {
    strncpy(&my_tab_str[i*(len+1)], person_name, len);
}
```

This is just a guess though, because that function really isn't well-documented.

Obviously, you will also need some cleanup code at some point that carefully `free`s everything.

And if you want to be really careful, you should add error-handling code that checks the result of each `calloc` for `NULL`, but that would clutter the example, so I've omitted it.

Comment: Good question --- I updated original posting with `OCI_BindArrayOfStrings` info. I'm hoping the example shown in the first link clarifies it beyond a doubt. It appears they cast it using `(char*)`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @ggkmath: Hmm, it looks like they're expecting a 1D array of char, and to be provided the dimensions as arguments.  Technically, accessing a 2D array via a 1D pointer is undefined behaviour, but if you give me a couple of minutes, I'll update my answer...

Comment: I originally wrote my code using `char **my_tab_str` (adjusted accordingly) and everything compiled fine. But got a segmentation fault then OCILIB tried to execute it's statements. I think when I declare it as such, and try to place `my_tab_str` into the `OCI_BindArrayOfStrings` it's not happy.

Comment: @ggkmath: Yeah, if that function really expects one big contiguous array, then giving it a `char **` will result in problems, because they're stored and accessed completely differently.

Comment: @ggkmath: If it takes a `char *`, then you need to to pass it a `char *`.  In my second code snippet, `my_tab_str` is already a `char *`, so it should already be fine.  But again, this is just a guess, because the documentation isn't clear.

Comment: With `-std=C89`, it doesn't allow variables in the declaration. Can I declare using `char *my_tab_str`, then later allocate using `my_tab_str = calloc(arraysize*(len+1), sizeof(*my_tab_str));`?

Comment: @ggkmath: yes.  But is there any reason you're restricting yourself to C89?

Comment: My gcc compiler version 4.4.4 doesn't fully support C99 features (http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/c99status.html) so I fell back to C89 to be consistent.

Comment: @ggkmath: Fair enough.  But you're really limiting yourself there!  It's much cleaner to be able to declare variables when they're needed.

Answer (score 2):

For array of strings, you need to declare my_tab_str as `char**` and then allocate memory for it.

```
my_tab_str = malloc(ROWS * sizeof(char*)); //ROW is no of strings
```

Then,

```
for(int i=0;i<ROWS;i++)
my_tab_str[i] = malloc(COLUMNS * sizeof(char)); //COLUMN is the size for each string.
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that by string, they mean `unsigned char *`.  You want an array of these, and they are using the (somewhat unusual) convention that an array of strings is a contiguous block of memory, so you declare it as:

```
unsigned char *my_tab_str;
size_t namesize = 20; // Better still, use a #define so 20 isn't a mysterious magic number
```

And you initialize it as follows:

```
my_tab_str = malloc( arraysize * sizeof( unsigned char *) * (namesize+1) ); // +1 for the null

for( int i = 0; i < arraysize; ++i )
    {
    strncpy( &my_tab_str[i*(namesize+1)], person_name, namesize );
    }
```

The first line (malloc) allocates enough memory for `arraysize` strings, each with room for `namesize` characters, plus a null.  The `strncpy` copies into each of them a maximum  `namesize` bytes, followed by a null ('\0').   Each time we pass a pointer to the next location, which is `namesize+1` bytes beyond the previous one.

Comment: Thanks DRVic, every element in array `my_tab_str` is exactly the same (they all contain "John Smith" plus null character). I know, this may seem strange, but that's how it needs to be. If you delare using `char **`, does this change the way `my_tab_str` is input into `OCI_BindArrayOfStrings` or is it as originally posted above?

Comment: from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887792/filling-a-string-buffer-when-using-ocilib I noted that it does not take an array of strings as is the normal convention, but rather a flat array.  Answer corrected.

Comment: Great find on that link. Why `unsigned char` instead of `char`? Could I replace `namesize` with `strlen(person_name)` to try to save memory when `person_name` doesn't occupy all 20 bytes?

Comment: Why unsigned char? No idea.  That's just what I found the folks creating orclib had typedef'd string to.  Personally `char *` would make more sense to me.  As far as replacing `namesize` with `strlen( person_name)`, that would work fine.  I was trying to stay closer to the original code.